# Redirect if already authenticated - ember simple auth

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have registration and login working for my Ember app but for some reason 'routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated' is not working currently. Here is my setup:

#### `config/environment.js`

```
'ember-simple-auth': {
  authenticationRoute: 'auth.login',
  routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: 'rows',
  routeAfterAuthentication: 'rows'
}
```

But if I go to say `/auth/login` after I'm signed in it doesn't redirect me to the `rows` route. Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login route should extend `unauthenticated-route-mixin` mixin:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import UnauthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/unauthenticated-route-mixin';

export default Route.extend(UnauthenticatedRouteMixin, {
});
```